# Git Bash: Launch Application via Alias without hanging Bash (WIndows)

Tags: git, bash

I've created several bash aliases in Git Bash on Windows, to launch executables from the bash shell.

The problem I am having is that is seems the bash is waiting for an exit code before it starts responding to input again, as once I close the app it launched, it starts taking commands again.

Is there a switch or something I can include in the alias so that bash doesn't wait for the exit code?

I'm looking for something like this...

```
alias np=notepad.exe --exit
```

Comment: have you tried running it with an &?
so instead of doing 

    > notepad.exe

    > notepad.exe &

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I confirm what [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21656/george) mentions in the comments:

Launching your alias with '`&`' allows you to go on without waiting for the return code.

[image]

With:

```
alias npp='notepad.exe&'
```

you won't even have to type in the '`&`'.

---

**But for including parameters**, I would recommend a **script (instead of an alias)** placed anywhere within your path, in a file called "`npp`":

```
/c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe $1 &
```

would allow you to open any file with "npp anyFile" (no '`&`' needed), without waiting for the return code.

A script like:

```
for file in $*
do
  /c/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe $file &
done
```

would launch several editors, one per file in parameters:

```
npp anyFile1 anyFile2 anyFile3
```

would allow you

Comment: Yes, I get that, but what if I want to execute notepad to open a file as well as not waiting for a return code ?

Answer (score 5):

Follow the command with an ampersand (`&`) to run it in the background.

Comment: Is it possible to include the & in the alias?  For example, I want to do this....  alias np='notepad.exe $*&', where the $* is the parameters specified when the alias is used...(the filename to open).

Comment: If you edit the git config file (`.git/config`) directly (in the `alias` section), you can probably add the `&` there. (You can't add it from the command line because it'll be interpreted as part of the command to set the alias, not part of the alias itself.)

Answer (score 3):

I combined the solution of VonC and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/1020871 to get an alias that launches an executable and passes along the parameters without locking the git bash. Add the following to the .bashrc:

```
npp() {
    notepad++.exe $* &
}

startGitk() {
    gitk $* &
}
alias gitk=startGitk
```

Now I can open several files notepad++ like `npp .gitignore build.gradle` or gitk with custom arguments like `gitk test -- .gitignore`.

I had a similar alias for npp as for gitk but found that I could call the function directly. I can also call startGitk but it didn't work when I named it gitk.